# Does gforth contain network socket capability?

Tags: sockets, networking, ip, forth, gforth

Often, when learning a language I'll write a server of some sort. Does [gforth](https://github.com/forthy42/gforth) have the capability to use network sockets?

I don't see anything about sockets in [the manual](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Though I don't see any documentation about it, there is a [`socket.fs`](https://github.com/forthy42/gforth/blob/master/unix/socket.fs) which binds to libc.

- [You can find some examples of FORTH that use sockets.fs on Rosetta Code](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category:Forth), specifically the [`ECHO` server example](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Echo_server#Forth)

Provided under the [GNU FDL, from Rossetta code by IanOsgood](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Echo_server#Forth) ([commit](https://rosettacode.org/mw/index.php?title=Echo_server&type=revision&diff=59626&oldid=50642))

```
include unix/socket.fs

128 constant size

: (echo) ( sock buf -- sock buf )
  begin
    cr ." waiting..."
    2dup 2dup size read-socket nip
    dup 0>
  while
    ."  got: " 2dup type
    rot write-socket
  repeat
  drop drop drop ;

create buf size allot

: echo-server ( port -- )
  cr ." Listening on " dup .
  create-server
  dup 4 listen
  begin
    dup accept-socket
    cr ." Connection!"
    buf ['] (echo) catch
    cr ." Disconnected (" . ." )"
    drop close-socket
  again ;

12321 echo-server
```

However, ymmv

```
nc localhost 12321
PING
PING
PONG
PONG
```

There are no Keepalives so you'll logically get disconnects from that.